# How correctly to join 2 dataframe in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new in **Apache Spark** and need some help. Can someone say how correctly to join next 2 dataframes?!

First dataframe:

```
| DATE_TIME           | PHONE_NUMBER |
|---------------------|--------------|
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 7056589658   |
| 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 7778965896   |
```

Second dataframe:

```
| DATE_TIME           | IP            |
|---------------------|---------------|
| 2019-01-01 01:00:00 | 194.67.45.126 |
| 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 102.85.62.100 |
| 2019-03-03 03:00:00 | 102.85.62.100 |
```

Final dataframe which I want:

```
| DATE_TIME           | PHONE_NUMBER | IP            |
|---------------------|--------------|---------------|
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 7056589658   |               |
| 2019-01-01 01:00:00 |              | 194.67.45.126 |
| 2019-02-02 00:00:00 | 7778965896   | 102.85.62.100 |
| 2019-03-03 03:00:00 |              | 102.85.62.100 |
```

Here below the code which I tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(
    ("2019-01-01 00:00:00", "7056589658"),
    ("2019-02-02 00:00:00", "7778965896")
).toDF("DATE_TIME", "PHONE_NUMBER")

df1.show()

val df2 = Seq(
    ("2019-01-01 01:00:00", "194.67.45.126"),
    ("2019-02-02 00:00:00", "102.85.62.100"),
    ("2019-03-03 03:00:00", "102.85.62.100")
).toDF("DATE_TIME", "IP")

df2.show()

val total = df1.join(df2, Seq("DATE_TIME"), "left_outer")

total.show()
```

Unfortunately, it raise error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
  at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doExecuteBroadcast(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:367)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:140)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoinExec.prepareBroadcast(BroadcastHashJoinExec.scala:135)
...
```

Comment: It seems correct to me except the join type needs to be `full` to get the desired result. Maybe the issue is in the configuration, could you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `full outer join`, but your code is good. Your issue might be some thing else, but with the stack trace you mentioned can't conclude what the issue is.

```
val total = df1.join(df2, Seq("DATE_TIME"), "full_outer")
```

Comment: I tested code in Zeppelin. I found the error reason. In my case I selected incorrect `interpreter binding` at start. `full_outer` exactly what I need. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
val total = df1.join(df2, (df1("DATE_TIME") === df2("DATE_TIME")), "left_outer")
```